# Swift Triggering Segue upon special if else conditions

Tags: ios, swift

I've followed documentation briefly and this is what I have so far:

ViewController.swift

```
 let x = "Registered!";
 let y =  jsonData.value(forKey: "results") as! String?;             
 let isEqual = (x == y)
 print(isEqual) // Gives me true or false works as expected
 if(isEqual==true){
  self.performSegue(withIdentifier:"Test", sender: self);

}
```

I'm trying to see if a condition is true; then execute the Segue.

I've created Segue in my storyboard like this.

I have two View Controller.

First View and Second View.
I then pressed cntrl and dragged the button from first view to second view creating a Segue.
I then gave my Segue a unique identifier "Test"

However; I want to only execute the new view only if the statement is true or else void it and throw an error message; however my segue seems to be working; it redirects to my second page weather the condition is true or not.

I also made sure; that my second view has a class and it's been set-up properly. No idea; why it keeps redirecting user to another view regardless of the statement. What could I have possibly done wrong?

Comment: Is that your real `if` statement? If so, what is `isEqual` and how is it set? If not, post real code. And where is this code? Provide some context.

Comment: That is indeed my real if statement. It gives me a boolean value; and it works as expected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The thing is that your segue is from Button to ViewController. You should drag and drop the segue with same identifier from ViewController to ViewController. Not from Button to ViewController

Comment: This worked for me! I was doing  button to  ViewController.